# Grails upgrade from 1.3.7 to 2.0.1 -

Tags: grails

I have upgraded my grails app from 1.3.7 to 2.0.1. I had few static (gsp but not using any controllers) pages using standard layout under "grails-app\views\" . These files were working fine prior to upgrade. But after upgrade, I get 404 error. Only index.gsp is working if I give root path ie. "http://localhost:8080/myapp/". But if I specify "http://localhost:8080/myapp/index.gsp", I get 404 error.

I assume this is something to do with grails filters in 2.0.1. But i couldn't figure it out yet. DO anyone have experienced any similar issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a security risk and directly linking to GSPs was disallowed in 2.0 - see http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7542 and http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Direct-linking-to-gsp-in-Grails-2-0-td4228929.html for a discussion and examples of how to use URL mappings to link to GSPs.